# where to find real time data non-delayed of N225 and AXJO

Tags: market-data, indexes

I found [marketindex.com](http://www.marketindex.com.au/asx200) real time data for the Austrial market index AXJO.

Is there a similar website for the Nikkei Index N225? On all websites it is always 20 minutes delayed, such as yahoo finance.

ALso, does Interactive brokers have this data in real time?

Real time as of delay of max. 1 second or less.

Comment: Are you willing to pay?

Comment: sure if it is affordable per month, i used activetick.com, but they dont have any non US market data really

Comment: Can you give some guidance on affordable?

Comment: max 200 per month, but then it should include everything, US markets, German, Australian, Japan, Indices in real time and history.

Comment: @BobJansen what suggestions did u have?

Comment: I have been following: https://tradingeconomics.com/australia/stock-market, but the data points at market close UTC 6am are different from yahoo finance https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EAXJO/history?p=%5EAXJO Where can I get the AXJO close price exactly at 6am UTC without having to wait 20 minutes until yahoo has it?